# Retriving data from different tables depending on value in a column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please pardon me if this question has been asked before, but I simply don't have enough vocabulary to search for what I need as a novice in data bases.

I am using SQL server 2008.
I have a table `tblPDCDetails` with several columns. One of the columns `PDCof` holds values :

```
"A"(for applicant), 
"C" for coapplicant, 
"G" (for Guarantor).
```

Another column `HolderID` holds uniqueid (of holder). 
The `PDCHolders` reside in their respective tables: Applicants in `tblApplBasicDetails`, `CoApllicants` in their own table and so on.

Now what I need is how  should I retrive the names of holders from their respective tables, depending on the value in `PDCof` column.

Can I do it at all?
If no how should I work around this?

Answer (score 3):

This should do:

```
SELECT  A.*,
        COALESCE(B.Name,C.Name,D.Name) Name
FROM dbo.tblPDCDetails A
LEFT JOIN dbo.tblApplBasicDetails B
    ON A.HolderID = B.HolderID
    AND A.PDCof = 'A'
LEFT JOIN dbo.tblCoApplBasicDetails C
    ON A.HolderID = C.HolderID
    AND A.PDCof = 'C'
LEFT JOIN dbo.tblGuarantorlBasicDetails D
    ON A.HolderID = D.HolderID
    AND A.PDCof = 'G'
```

Answer (score 0):

The other option is to use a case switch:

```
Select case Main.PDCof
    when 'A' then (select HolderID from Applicants where main.value = value)
    when 'C' then (select HolderID from CoApplicants where main.value = value)
    when 'G' then (select HolderID from Guarantor where main.value = value)
    end
    ,main.*
from tblPDCDetails main
```

Depends on whether you run this a few times a day, or a few thousand times an hour